# How can I have *both* Markdown header folding and indent folding in Vim

Tags: vim, markdown, folding

Vim now has built-in Markdown folding, yay!

I want to fold on Markdown headers, and within headers, fold on indents also.

How can I have *both* Markdown header folding + indent fold method at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

There can only be one of Vim's [standard fold methods](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-methods) used within an individual window, but what you ask should still be possible. Here are a few options that I can think of:

- You can use the [`expr`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr) method option and create your own [custom rules](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'foldexpr') with that. This is probably the only "real" way to get what you want, but it's the most complicated option.
- You could also use two windows in a tab, each pointing at the same buffer, and set different fold methods locally for each split.
- Finally, you could always hack something together with autocommands. From the Vim wiki page [on folding](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Folding), about having both indent and manual folding:

  ```
  augroup vimrc
    au BufReadPre * setlocal foldmethod=indent
    au BufWinEnter * if &fdm == 'indent' | setlocal foldmethod=manual | endif
  augroup END
  ```

  This hack takes advantage of [modelines](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'modeline'), and Vim's behavior for setting variables before vs. after the modeline is read. Note that you have to have Vim's `nocompatible` option set for this sort of trick to work.